# Is that possible to install language pack offlinely?

Tags: 12.04, installation, language-support, offline

I have a laptop, and I want to install Indonesian language pack. Unfortunately, there is no Internet connection. Can I install language packs offline (assuming I can download files in another computer)?

Log:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-id-base/language-pack-gnome-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id-base/language-pack-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id/language-pack-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-id/language-pack-gnome-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-id_11.0+build1-0ubuntu4_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-l10n-id_3.5.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openoffice.org-hyphenation/openoffice.org-hyphenation_0.6_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler-data/poppler-data_0.4.5-2_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-locale-id_11.0.1+build1-0ubuntu2_all.deb Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

*edit:* I've trying myself to run terminal and use `gksudo file-roller` to open Archive manager with elevated rights, and extract all of contents of package manually, but didn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do it.open your terminal and paste these lines one by one

```
mkdir lan
cd lan
wget http://shadow.ind.ntou.edu.tw/ubuntu//pool/main/l/language-pack-id-base/language-pack-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb
wget http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id/language-pack-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

for more information: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/translations/

Answer (score 1):

Download the .deb packages and install them with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

To download them:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-id-base/language-pack-gnome-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id-base/language-pack-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id/language-pack-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-id/language-pack-gnome-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-id_11.0+build1-0ubuntu4_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-l10n-id_3.5.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openoffice.org-hyphenation/openoffice.org-hyphenation_0.6_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler-data/poppler-data_0.4.5-2_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-locale-id_11.0.1+build1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download those packages, and then use `dpkg` to install them manually.

**How to download the packages**

Run the command

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-locale-id_11.0+build1-0ubuntu4_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-l10n-id_3.5.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-id-base/language-pack-gnome-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-id/language-pack-gnome-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id-base/language-pack-id-base_12.04+20120417_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-id/language-pack-id_12.04+20120417_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openoffice.org-hyphenation/openoffice.org-hyphenation_0.6_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/poppler-data/poppler-data_0.4.5-2_all.deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird-locale-id_11.0.1+build1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

(it is a long command line; once you run it, it will download all packages that you referenced above).

**How to install the packages**

Run the command

```
sudo dpkg -i *deb
```

(assuming that no other .deb files exist in the same direcory).

That's it!

Comment: just a small improvement: I recommend downloading the *.deb files in /tmp so that they are discarded after reboot.

Comment: Where I should place downloaded packages (*.deb)? _edit:_ I mean I'd downloaded it on another computer, and copying it to usb-drive.

Comment: @AryoAdhiWibisonoLegopermono: Since the .deb files will be used only once when running the `sudo dpkg -i *deb`, you do not need to place the files in a special location. Simply locate them in your terminal window and then run the command.